# How does this class implement IDisposable if it doesn't have a Dispose method?

Tags: c#, interface, idisposable, ftpwebresponse

[FtpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhk72sf2.aspx) implements IDisposable, but it doesn't have a Dispose method.  How is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does have the Dispose method through inheritance, but it is an explicit implementation. To call it, you would have to use

```
((IDisposable)myObject).Dispose();
```

Or, of course, just wrap it in a `using` block, as it does the explicit call for you.

Comment: +1 for mentioning its explicitly implemented.  As others have said its on the base, but you'd still see it - you answered why you can't easily see it.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind using an explicit implementation?

Comment: @MCS, that's a good question! Actually, it sounds like a good *new* question for stackoverflow of why some classes have explicit IDisposable implementations, as it sort of masks the fact that the object should be disposed for the average developer who is not consulting the documentation every time he/she uses a class.

Answer (score 10):

Its implemented in the base class WebResponse, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse_methods.aspx

Comment: I don't see any Dispose method there either.

Comment: Scroll down to "Explicit Interface Implementations"

Comment: Oh, it is there, just further down the page under "Explicit Interface Implementations."  Why is that?  And why doesn't this method show up in IntelliSense when I have an instance of FtpWebResponse?

Answer (score 4):

When you implement an `interface` explicitly, you won't get the method in the listing. You will have to cast that object to implemented `interface` to get access to that method.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's implemented in the base class WebResponse

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
try
{
    this.Close();
    this.OnDispose();
}
catch
{
}
}
```

[alt text http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/2428/redgatesnetreflector.png](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/2428/redgatesnetreflector.png)

Answer (score 2):

It inherits from [System.Net.WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse_members.aspx) which implements these methods.