# Does the FtpWebResponse IDisposable close the response?

Tags: c#, idisposable, using, ftpwebresponse

I'm using the following code in my program, would I still need to call `response.close()`? Or does the `FtpWebResponse IDisposable` implementation close the response?

```
using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{

}
```

So basically, would I need to do this?

```
using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    response.close();
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, is it going to cost me more if the close method will be called twice?

Comment: @Izikon Would it? As far as I know my whole application would crash if I did. Perhaps you could be a bit more specific instead of asking a question.

Comment: This question is an interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119288/why-would-a-class-implement-idisposable-explicitly-instead-of-implicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't have to call `Close`, since `Dispose` already does that. `FtpWebResponse` is inherited from `WebResponse` and it has explicitly implemented `Dispose`, which internally call `Close`.

Code for `WebResponse.cs` from : http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Net/System/Net/WebResponse@cs/1305376/WebResponse@cs

```
 /// <internalonly>
        void IDisposable.Dispose() {
            try
            {
                Close();
                OnDispose();
            }
            catch { }
        }
```