# Why can I use using, but not object.dispose()?

Tags: c#

I was playing around with `System.Net.HttpListenerResponse` today, and I noticed that there is still apparently a gap in my knowledge regarding `using`.

```
using (HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Is perfectly valid code, however, the object has no Dispose() method.

Why does `using` still work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IDisposable.Dispose` is implemented explicitly in `System.Net.HttpListenerResponse`. To call it from your code you have to cast it to `IDisposable` first.

```
HttpListenerResponse response = GetResponse();

// doesn't work
response.Dispose();

// do work
((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerresponse(v=vs.110).aspx), the `HttpListenerResponse` does implement `IDisposable`. The interface is implemented explicitly though, as listed under "Explicit Interface Implementations":

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
```

As explained in [C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation):

> Explicit implentation allows it to only be accessible when cast as the interface itself.

So you'll have to cast it as `IDisposable` in order to call the method:

```
((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
```

It is [appropriately documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302648(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

See also [Why would a class implement IDisposable explicitly instead of implicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119288/why-would-a-class-implement-idisposable-explicitly-instead-of-implicitly).

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpListenerResponse` inherits from `IDisposable` thus allowing the `using` statements to auto call the `Dispose()` method when complete.

The `HttpListenerResponse` explicitly defines the `Dispose()` method as below. (Taken from decompile).

```
void System.IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```