# How to call Dispose on a concrete implemenation of a C# class

Tags: c#, dispose

If I use the following structure:

```
public class TestClass : IDisposable
{
    private SqlBulkCopy _bulkCopy;
    public TestClass(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        _bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_bulkCopy != null)
                _bulkCopy.Dispose(); // Cannot call dispose as this is a concrete implementation
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot access the dispose function on my `_bulkCopy` object.

I know I can use a `using` statement, but is that the only way?

I would prefer not to as this means I may have to keep recreating this object

I know I could also wrap an interface around this, but is there any other way?

Comment: When you say, "I cannot access the dispose function on my _bulkCopy object.", is that a compiler message?

Comment: *I cannot access the dispose function on my _bulkCopy object.* why?

Comment: Cast it to IDisposable?

Comment: `void Dispose(bool disposing)` when would this boolean ever be false? If you're not disposing, you shouldn't be calling the `Dispose` method.

Comment: @Flater https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken no it is because it is a concrete implementation and so the class does not have this method.

Comment: @Selvin see my comment above

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` implements the interface explicitly so you have to cast to `IDisposable`: `((IDisposable)_bulkCopy).Dispose()`.

Comment: @Selvin, as Lee has elaborated on my comment, the method does 'exist' but it has been explicitly implemented so a cast is required.

Comment: @Lee as long as it's `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` not some *concrete implementation* whatever it means

Comment: It's "how to call an explicitly implemented interface method given a reference to the implementing class."

Comment: Reproduced it and the error was:

Compilation error (line 31, col 27): 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose' etc. Lee's comment fixes this

Comment: @the.Doc  if you want to add that as answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Lee same comment as above for you

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338425/can-an-idispose-objects-not-have-an-available-dispose-method or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118861/how-does-this-class-implement-idisposable-if-it-doesnt-have-a-dispose-method ... which are first result for "stackoverflow  IDisposable doesn't have a Dispose method"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen [when an interface is explicitly implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). First, a basic example of an implicitly implemented interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void FooTheBar();
}

public class ImplicitImplementer : IFoo
{
    public void FooTheBar()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This can be used the way you expect it to, both by its concrete type and the interface:

```
ImplicitImplementer a = new ImplicitImplementer();
a.FooTheBar(); // works

IFoo b = new ImplicitImplementer();
b.FooTheBar(); // works
```

But when you explicitly implement an interface, you **must** use the interface type.

```
public class ExplicitImplementer : IFoo
{
    public void IFoo.FooTheBar()  // Notice the "IFoo."
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Notice the consequences:

```
ExplicitImplementer a = new ExplicitImplementer();
a.FooTheBar(); // ERROR!

IFoo b = new ExplicitImplementer();
b.FooTheBar(); // works
```

That's just how it works. I suspect that your `SqlBulkCopy` class explicitly implements `IDisposable`, which means you're going to have to cast it to the correct interface:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (_bulkCopy != null)
            (_bulkCopy as IDisposable).Dispose();
    }
}
```

I prefer the `as` syntax, but you can use `(IDisposable) _bulkCopy` if you prefer. You can actually slightly improve the flow of the code here:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        (_bulkCopy as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This prevents exceptions both in the case of `_bulkCopy` being null or `_bulkCopy` no longer implementing `IDisposable` anymore. It disposes if it can, and otherwise it does nothing.

---

It may seem weird why this is ever useful, and it doesn't quite seem necessary in your case. Explicit implementation is only useful when a class implements multiple interfaces that have a clashing interface member, e.g.:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void FooTheBar();
}    

public interface IBar
{
    void FooTheBar();
}

public class FooBar : IFoo, IBar
{
    public void FooTheBar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IFoo or IBar?");
    }
}
```

This code actually works, but the same method will be called regardless of whether you do:

```
IFoo a = new FooBar();
a.FooTheBar(); // "IFoo or IBar?"

IBar b = new FooBar();
b.FooTheBar(); // "IFoo or IBar?"
```

But what if you want these two methods to be **separate**? Well, then you explicitly label each method implementation as belonging to a specific interface. That's what explicit implementation is.

```
public class FooBar : IFoo, IBar
{
    public void IFoo.FooTheBar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IFoo");
    }

    public void IBar.FooTheBar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IBar");
    }
}
```

And then you'll see:

```
IFoo a = new FooBar();
a.FooTheBar(); // "IFoo"

IBar b = new FooBar();
b.FooTheBar(); // "IBar"
```

But since you've restricted these methods to the specific interfaces, `FooBar` itself cannot resolve to a specific `FooTheBar` method anymore, hence the error you're faced with. It's a consequence of a solution to another problem (i.e. overlapping interfaces).